# Edit is working fine when all entites are in TextBox else giving Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am using MVC 3.0 with EF
I have Table which contain Identity column with Auto Increment 1. Now i created a View for Edit with only FirstName,LastName and ID will be ReadOnly mode.  Now i changed value First Name and Last Name and press submit button then **it will gives me an error**:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'colID' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Edit(Int32,
>   CAFM.Business.Models.TabMasterViewModel)'
>   in
>   'CAFM.Web.Controllers.TabMasterController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

If i set ID from RedaOnly to Edit

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
```

to

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
```

then it is working perfectly.

Please provide your valuable suggestions!

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is quite obvious. When you post edits back to server it doesn't post Id because Id is not in any HTML control - it is just a text. Because of that you cannot create valid entity for saving. You must always post Id back (for example in hidden field) and have some validation that the Id was not changed or that user still have permissions to change the record.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. can you please provide help for set Identity Column to Hidden Field, because of i am very new in MVC.

Comment: I believe this should work: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)`